# How can one use Grid Search without overfitting the model?

Tags: model-selection, scikit-learn, overfitting, hyperparameter, tuning

I checked several questions, like [Overfitting during model selection - AutoML vs Grid search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306070/overfitting-during-model-selection-automl-vs-grid-search) and [Hyperparameter tuning using grid search/randomised search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386487/hyperparameter-tuning-using-grid-search-randomised-search), but I don't think any of them answer my question (even though I believe is a very common one).

So I was using RandomSearchCV from scikit-learn in order to tune the hyperparameters of a Random Forest Regression (and other models). However, I believe I'm getting overfitted models. In some cases, the root mean square error in the training dataset is less than half of the testing dataset. Is there a way of using some sort of Grid Search and not get an overfitted model? I mean, how can I get a good hyperparameter tuning without overfitting my model?